# regex matching only currency with upto six figure value with 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried the following thinking it would work but it doesn't why

```
[^\d{1,6}\.][\d{2,2}]$
```

i.e.

- 999999.99 (maximum shud accept)
- 9.25
- 25.25

so I 'm trying to this in javascript

Comment: Probably because you want to match sequences of patterns, `^\d{1,6}\.\d{2}$`

Comment: Please share sample inputs which should work and which shouldn't.

Comment: test it here https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempted regex has two character classes. So basically your regex will only match 2 character strings like `a2`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/OMISoN/1) for the explanation.

You should remove the `[]` so that it no longer denotes 2 character classes:

```
^\d{1,6}\.\d{2,2}$
```